# Getting multiple array using aggregate method in MongoDB and Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to fetch data from MongoDB document using `aggregate` method but here I could not formatted data as expected. I am providing my document below.

```
{
    "zone_list":[{
        "zone":'NORTH',
        "state_list":[{
            "state":"DELHI",
            "location_list":[{
                "location":"NEW DELHI",
                "task_list":[{
                    "login_id":"9937229853"
                },{
                   "login_id":"9937229854" 
                }]
            },{
                "location":"AIRPORT",
                "task_list":[{
                    "login_id":"9937229855"
                }]
            }]
        },{
           "state":"JK",
            "location_list":[{
                "location":"NEW JK",
                "task_list":[{
                    "login_id":"9937229853"
                },{
                   "login_id":"9937229857" 
                }]
            },{
                "location":"AIRPORT JK",
                "task_list":[{
                    "login_id":"9937229858"
                }]
            }] 
        }]
    },{
        "zone":'EAST',
        "state_list":[{
            "state":"WB",
            "location_list":[{
                "location":"KOLKATA",
                "task_list":[{
                    "login_id":"9937229859"
                },{
                   "login_id":"9937229850" 
                }]
            },{
                "location":"ASAM",
                "task_list":[{
                    "login_id":"9937229895"
                }]
            }]
        },{
           "state":"ODISHA",
            "location_list":[{
                "location":"BHUBANESWAR",
                "task_list":[{
                    "login_id":"9937229844"
                },{
                   "login_id":"9937229845" 
                }]
            },{
                "location":"AIRPORT BBSR",
                "task_list":[{
                    "login_id":"9937229846"
                }]
            }] 
        }]
    }]
}
```

Here I need to fetch the data as per login_id and my query is given below.

```
var login_id=9937229853;
    //console.log('login',login_id);
    Allocation.collection.aggregate([ 
    //{$match:{}},
    {$unwind:"$zone_list"},
    {$unwind:"$zone_list.state_list"},
    {$unwind:"$zone_list.state_list.location_list"},
    {$unwind:"$zone_list.state_list.location_list.task_list"},
    //{$match:{zone:zoneInput,state:stateInput,location:locationInput}}
    {$match: {
            "zone_list.state_list.location_list.task_list.login_id": login_id
    }}
    ])
    .toArray((err,docs)=>{
        if (!err) {
            var data={'status':'success','data':docs}
            res.send(data);
        }
    })
```

Here I am getting the right filter data but its not well formatted. Here I am getting zone record 2 times where that `login_id` is present within the same zone. I need if search `login _id` is present in that document then it should fetch as per that document format.

Comment: The problem here is that you're unwinding arrays, which convert an array into separate records per value in the array, you will need to [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) the records (back) into the shape you're after. Basically inverting all the `$unwind` stages

Comment: @RogierSpieker: Can you updated your query ?